# Isolating CSS styles in multi-level menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I am styling my menu and for some reason it is affecting the sub-menu of the current menu item. Linked below, two menu screenshots from the same page.

[Lines Above Sub Menu Items](http://138.1b3.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/menupurpleline.png)

[No Lines Above Sub Menu Items](http://138.1b3.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/menunopurple.png)

This is my only styling for the line-above thing I am going with:

```
#topmenu ul a:hover {
   border-top: 2px solid #771e98;
    color: #f2f2f2;
}


#topmenu .current-menu-item a {
    border-top: 2px solid #771e98;
    color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Am I missing something? I just want the sub-menu items under 'Home' to be normal black, without the purple line above that indicates a selected or hovered link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're only styling the parent ul. I think you have the parent ul enclosed withing `#topmenu`

You would need something like this to style the drop down menu:

```
#topmenu > ul > li > ul a:hover{
}
```

Kind of hard to figure out without the relevant HTML code.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem! I knew it was something simple like this, I just couldn't put my finger on it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that only child elements be styled, and not all descendants. I'm guessing here because you haven't shown your HTML, but you get the idea.

```
#topmenu > ul > li.current-menu-item > a,
#topmenu > ul > li > a:hover { ... }
```

**[More on child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)**